# mappings on vim throwing an error (E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &)

Tags: vim

Hi I'm using MacVim 7.3
I'm following a PeepCode tutorial called [smash into vim](https://peepcode.com/products/smash-into-vim-i).

One of the topics is to assign various "mappings" (I think of them as shortcuts or aliases) for certain commands.

For example, here is part of my .**vimrc** file (see below)
The help files say that  is assigned as backslash (\) by default.  However, when I enter command-line mode and type :\tt I get the following error:

**E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &**

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?  I can tell that my .vimrc file is being used by macvim b/c I used the file to swap the semi-colon and colon bindings and now ; will cause the editor to enter command-line mode.

```
" Tab mappings.
map <leader>tt :tabnew<cr>
map <leader>te :tabedit
map <leader>tc :tabclose<cr>
map <leader>to :tabonly<cr>
map <leader>tn :tabnext<cr>
map <leader>tp :tabprevious<cr>
map <leader>tf :tabfirst<cr>
map <leader>tl :tablast<cr>
map <leader>tm :tabmove


" Controversial...swap colon and semicolon for easier commands
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;

vnoremap ; :
vnoremap : ;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are mapping something like  `<leader>tt` it does not work in command mode (invoked using `:`) but in normal mode.

So all you have to do is to type `\tt` without `:` and see what happens : a new tab should open hopefully.

Regarding the use of `<leader>` in defining a new mapping, the main interest is that, if you are not satisfied with the use of `\`, you can redefine the  key the following way at the beginning of your `.vimrc`:

`:let mapleader = ","`

and you leader key will change in every subsequent mapping command : `\tt` becomes `,tt`

Good luck on your way to become a proficient Vim user !

Comment: You speak the truth, my faithful and young companion.  Thanks for this!

Comment: good job, no one mentions the command (:) vs normal mode - without ':' when describing using leaders- this is very helpful to newbies

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems: one is that you are using `map` and then remap semicolon, so `map <leader>tt :tabnew<CR>` tries to execute `;tabnew<CR>` (`;` repeats previous t/T/f/F motion, `ta` moves cursor to next `a`, `n` tries to repeat previous search and so on) and it won't work. You should use `noremap` where possible, do not use `map` without `nore` unless you know what you are doing (and I also suggest changing `noremap` to `nnoremap` here: I don't think you need to change tabs from visual and, especially, operator-pending modes). Second problem is that `noremap` remaps commands in normal mode, so you need to type `\tt`, not `:\tt` or `;\tt`.

Comment: Thanks to you as well.  I was just switching ; and : functionality to see if my .vimrc file was being "used" properly, but I hadn't fully appreciated the nuance that you pointed out here.