# Writing a custom :Command that uses normal mode features

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

For this example, I would like the custom `:EasyMotion` command to have the same effect as `<Leader><Leader>w` in normal mode. To achieve this, I have tried adding the following to my vimrc.

```
command EasyMotion <Leader><Leader>w
```

This does not work. Using this command causes the error **E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &** to appear.

I understand why this is -- as this [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766783/2624466) explains, my `:EasyMotion` command is equivalent to `:\\w`, which is not valid. But how do I get around this? How do I write a custom command that uses a feature that can only be used normal mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `normal` command:

```
command EasyMotion normal <Leader><Leader>w
```

Comment: It looks like this approach does leave one issue unsolved. Features that expect input (like, strangely enough, EasyMotion) fail when they are called this way. That is, when I use `<Leader><Leader>w` I am correctly asked for input, but when I use `:EasyMotion` I am not, and I get an error from the EasyMotion plugin. Is there any way around that?